# Outer margins in pairs() function

Tags: r, plot

I have too much whitespace around the outside of my `pairs()` plot. How can one control the outer margins in a `pairs()` plot?

Changing `oma` for example does nothing (i.e. `par(oma=c(0,0,0,0))` makes no difference).

Comment: try adjusting the margin parameters `par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))`. 
You'll have to play around with the numbers though to get the spacing you want.

Comment: Look at the last example in `?pairs`

Comment: `mar` does nothing as well, at least when I output to `cairo_pdf`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr** use `oma` as an argument within your `pairs()` call.

As usual, it's all in the documentation, albeit somewhat obscurely. `?pairs` states:

> Also, graphical parameters can be given as can arguments to
>             ‘plot’ such as ‘main’.  ‘par("oma")’ will be set
>             appropriately unless specified.

This means that `pairs()` tries to do some clever stuff internally to set the outer margins (based on whether a `main` title is requested); it will ignore external `par("oma")` settings, only paying attention to internal settings.  The "offending" line within the code of `stats:::pairs.default` is:

```
  if (is.null(oma)) 
        oma <- c(4, 4, if (!is.null(main)) 6 else 4, 4)
```

Thus setting `oma` *within* the call does work:

```
par(bg="lightblue")  ## so we can see the plot region ...
z <- matrix(rnorm(300),ncol=3)
pairs(z,oma=c(0,0,0,0))
```

[image]